# Issue using session variable in an onload function

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I am trying to create an alert box after a servlet call depending on the value in one of my input fields 'UpdCMDStatus'.  It seems that I need to put this in the onload event of my JSP program (correct me if wrong).  Here is my script function call at the end of the HTML

```
           window.onload = confirmProcess;

           function confirmProcess()
              {

                var statusCheck = $('#UpdCMDStatus').val();
                alert("Status Check pulled is " + statusCheck );

                if (statusCheck === "CP" || statusCheck === "RP")
                {
                    var modifymode = $('#RecordFlag').val();
                    alert ("Modify Mode flag is " + modifymode) ;
                    if (modifymode === "Y")
                    {
                       alert("Schedule Numbers for Status 'VP' and 'CP' cannot " +
                                   " be Updated")    ;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                      var modifymode = $('#RecordFlag').val();
                      alert ("Modify Mode flag if status is not CP/RP is " + modifymode) ;  

                   }

               }


           }     ;
```

Here is my processing of this #RecordFlag session variable in the EFTscreen servlet:

```
   if (action.matches("searchMEFTS"))
    {
        System.out.println("Entering the process to go to MEFTS screen.  Continue");
        session.setAttribute("RecordFlag", " ");

        if (screenaccess.matches("mainEFT"))
        {
           String startStatus = "NP" ;
           session.setAttribute("UpdCMDStatus", startStatus);



           session.setAttribute("UpdCMDCreationDate", CMDcurrentdate);

           wkStatus = startStatus; 


        }
        else
        {    

           wkStatus = request.getParameter("UpdCMDStatus");
           session.setAttribute("UpdCMDStatus", wkStatus);

           wkCreation = request.getParameter("UpdCMDCreationDate");
           session.setAttribute("UpdCMDCreationDate", wkCreation);
           session.setAttribute("RecordFlag", "Y");

        }


       Sum_EFTBean meftsResults = new Sum_EFTBean() ;
       List<Sum_EFTBean> Updresults ; 
       Updresults = EFTQuery.selectDates(wkStatus, wkCreation) ;
       numberOfEntries = Updresults.size() ; 
       url = "/updatesched.jsp";

       if (numberOfEntries == 0) 
         {
           message = ("No open EFT Schedule Numbers found") ;
           session.setAttribute("messageMEFS",message) ;

         }
       else      
        {    
         session.setAttribute("Updresults", Updresults);


        } 

    }
```

On the alert statement checking the modifymode field it is showing up as undefined.  Is the problem with using the session variable is because of the load event or do you see any other issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that all of your input fields will be reset(cleared) once you submit the form. Of course, in your servlet you can create, say ,an attribute showAlert and set it as a request attribute.

```
boolean showAlert = request.getParameter("updCMDStatus").equals("someValue") ?true:false;
request.setAttribute("showAlert", showAlert)
```

Then in your java script, you would simply write

```
function confirmProcess(){

  if( ${showAlert} )//this EL expression will be replaced by either true or false
    //do something
}
```